# how can I have multiple forms each generated from a list of items?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

In an MVC application, I have a list of exam questions and I want to present a small number of them to the user on the same page but where each answer can be submitted separately.
So my page looks like this ....
[image]

The view code is ....

```cs
    @model List<QuestionResponseVM>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
      using (Html.BeginForm("CheckQuestions", "Checks", FormMethod.Post, new {questResponses = Model[i] }))
      {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].QuestionID)
        <tr>
          <td width="35%">
            @Html.Raw(Model[i].QuestionText)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].QuestionText)
          </td>
          <td>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model[i].Response, new { @name = "DisplayTextEdit", @id = "DisplayTextEdit", @rows = 1, @cols = 80 })
          </td>
          <td width="30%">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
              </div>
            </div>

          </td>
        </tr>
      }
    }
```

My problem is I can only get data returned to the POST method for Question 1.
Here is the Controller Code ....

```cs
  public class ChecksController : Controller  
  {  
  
    public ActionResult CheckQuestions()
    {
      return View(LoadQuestions());
    }
  
    // POST: Checks
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CheckQuestions(List<QuestionResponseVM> questResponses)
    {
      List<QuestionResponseVM> testList = new List<QuestionResponseVM>();
  
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        testList = LoadQuestions(questResponses[0].QuestionID, questResponses[0].Response);
      }
  
      return View(testList);
  
    }
  
    private List<QuestionResponseVM> LoadQuestions (int _QuestionID = -1, string _Response = "")
    {
      List<QuestionResponseVM> thisList = new List<QuestionResponseVM>();
  
      thisList.Add(new QuestionResponseVM()
      {
        QuestionID = 1,
        QuestionText = "Question 1",
        Response = (_QuestionID == 1 ? _Response : "")
      });
      thisList.Add(new QuestionResponseVM()
      {
        QuestionID = 2,
        QuestionText = "Question 2",
        Response = (_QuestionID == 2 ? _Response : "")
      });
      thisList.Add(new QuestionResponseVM()
      {
        QuestionID = 3,
        QuestionText = "Question 3",
        Response = (_QuestionID == 3 ? _Response : "")
      });
  
      return thisList;
    }
  }
```

1. If the Controller POST method has a parameter of **QuestionResponseVM  questResponses**  which is what I was expecting (hoping for) then null is returned from the view no matter which "Save" button is clicked.
2. However, if I change the parameter to a list (i.e. **List<QuestionResponseVM> questResponses**) then the "Save" button for Question 1 returns a list with a single item and correct data. But, any other "Save" button (e.g. Question 2 or Question 3) returns a null list.

The behaviour for scenario 1. seems counter-intuitive to me since the "Begin Form" is set to return a single model item (instance of the model) i.e. "Model[i]".
And in scenario 2., I just don't understand why it works for the first form ("Save" button) but not for the others.

I don't believe I should need to use JScript or AJAX to do this.

But clearly, I am not "connecting some dots" here.
Can someone please explain my observed behaviour and maybe give me a push in the right direction to meet this requirement.?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: it is better to use ajax to submit forms, whereas in ajax you will not refresh the page after each submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going through your questions, I don't get what `new {questResponses = Model[i] }))` is doing in your forms:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("CheckQuestions", "Checks", FormMethod.Post, new {questResponses = Model[i] }))
{
    ...
}
```

`Model[i]` is a complex object. All you got there was the name of the object:

[image]

#### Q1: If the Controller POST method has just a single parameter

Since you're using a for loop to generate each form and inputs within the form, the name of those inputs will be in the forms of `[INDEX].NAME`:

[image]

By default, the model binding will bind those inputs (QuestionId, QuestionText and Response) to a matching object. `QuestionResponseViewModel` indeed matches that. The problem is `[INDEX].` prefix.

In order for the default model binding to work, the parameter name you declare in the POST method has to be called `[INDEX]`, i.e., `[0]` for the first form, `[1]` for the second form and so on:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CheckQuestions(QuestionResponseVM [0])
{
    ...
}
```

But you know we can't declare anything like that in C#.

#### The Fix for Q1

Instead of using the regular for loop, you can use `foreach` to generate each form. In that way, you get rid of the need for naming a parameter that's changing for each form.

Another "GOTYOU" here is that the parameter in the controller **has to** match the variable you declared in the for loop for each `QuestionResponseViewModel`:

```
@foreach (var qrVM in Model)
{
    using(Html.BeginForm("..."))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => qrVM.QuestionId)

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => qrVM.QuestionId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => qrVM.QuestionId)
            </td>
            ...
        </tr>
    }
}
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult CheckQuestions(QuestionResponseVM qrVM)
{
    // If you name the parameter something else, it won't bind!
    ...
}
```

If you think about it, that makes sense, because you know the form will post data with keys like `qrVM.QuestionId`, `qrVM.QuestionText` back to the server. The default model binding will search for a model that has those properties and is named `qrVM`.

[image]

#### Q2: Change parameter to a list

When the first form posts back to the server, the form data in the request body will look like:

```
[0].RequestionId: 1
[0].RequestionText: Question 1
[0].Response: xxx
```

MVC model binding is still smart enough and thinks you're posting the first item of the list you declared. Hence you will see `List<QuestionResponseVM> questResponses` capture the correct data for the first form.

Well what about the second and third form? If you submit the data on the second form for example, the form data in the request body will look like:

```
[1].RequestionId: 2
[1].RequestionText: Question 2
[1].Response: xxx
```

MVC model binding sees it as the 2nd item of the list, but where's the 1st item? And it got confused so it couldn't bind the data to the parameter. Hence you will see NULL from the parameter `List<QuestionResponseVM> questResponses`.

#### My 2 cents

1. You actually cannot put a form inside a table or between table rows like this. It's considered as invalid HTML structure. It's never a good idea to use tables as structures to display data on the page anyway. Instead, You can use Bootstrap's row and columns.
2. I don't know why or what made you think you shouldn't need AJAX. Your case is like the best scenario to go with an AJAX approach! For example, with AJAX, the user can save each question's response individually. The page doesn't have to be refreshed.

Comment: ,Thank you for taking the time to provide such a comprehensive answer. For me, this is such valuable insight. At 69, I am still learning and as for AJAX ... I honestly have never used it before but it sounds like time it's high time I added another "arrow to my quiver".  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your save button on Question 1 is submitting the form to the controller.  You will need to either have one Save/Submit button at the end of a set of questions and utilize the FormCollection object or spend time setting up JQuery/Ajax for click events on each button and removing the form element.  You could have a bit of both if the button at the bottom becomes a 'Next' and then submits to a controller to get the next set of related questions.

Comment: Hi and thanks for replying. 
Your JQuery/Ajax idea follows-up nicely with a previous reply.
I have spent  time successfully playing with this idea and am confident that this is the way to go as the "Save each question individually" is a requirement, as is having multiple questions per page.